# Redirect to page question/guidance needed

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

This is more of a question than anything else, but I'll try my best to explain what I'd like to achieve:

If I have a Nuxt JavaScript SPA application with a number of pages set up, e.g. About Us, Services, Contact etc., and I'd like to redirect a user to a certain page and add some URL query parameters to the page as JavaScript variables how would I go about doing this?

Here's an example URL that I might enter and where I'd like it to go:

```
http://localhost:3000/follow?target=/about-us&first_name=John&last_name=Doe
```

If I'd visit that link, how could I tell Nuxt JavaScript to get the value of `target` which would then redirect the user to the About Us page for instance, bearing in mind that the page `follow` isn't actually a page?

Here's how I'm thinking of doing it:

I could setup a page which is called `follow.vue` inside of my pages directory, and then have some JavaScript within the mounted method which gets the value of `target` and redirects them to that page and then populates some variables with the first & last name.

I ideally need the redirect to happen before actually loading the view to prevent a flicker of an empty page and then being redirected.

Comment: What event is triggering the url above?